# Sleep will stop Nginx since it's an event-based server?

Tags: ruby, nginx, webserver, node.js, nonblocking

I think if you have `setTimeout=1` then the node server will be unavailable for all requests in 1 second since it's event-based, non-threaded web server (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've heard that Nginx is also an event-based web server. Doesn't that mean that if I have `sleep 1` then it would be halted for all requests in 1 second?

Comment: I'm not sure how nginx will behave in the face of `sleep`, but, while it's not thread-based, it has potentially more than one worker process: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule#worker_processes

Answer (score 0):

> I think if you have setTimeout=1 then the node server will be unavailable for all requests in 1 second since it's event-based, non-threaded web server (correct me if I'm wrong).

This is not correct. Node has an event loop, so when that one second has passed, it will return to the code in the `setTimeout` and run it. During the intervening time it will continue to serve requests and do work.

Note that if you wanted to stop EVERYTHING, you'd do a 
    while(true){}

If you have any other questions, feel free to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions.